# ResourceLoader returns empty strings

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp

I am trying to use a `*.resw` file in my UWP app to store localized strings. I am loading these strings through `ResourceLoader.GetString()` and am placing them in a `MessageDialog` for presentation to the user, but no matter what I do the return value of `GetString()` is an empty (zero-length) string. I am following the [SDK sample for localization](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ApplicationResources/cs/scenario3.xaml.cs#L55-L56), but am not getting the expected response.

The string I am trying to use is of the format `InvalidAssemblyDialog.Message`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out this problem was due to my using dots in the keys for my strings in the `*.resw` file. Dots are reserved, and my usage of them was causing name-resolution errors. In the case of the example above, I changed it to `InvalidAssemblyDialog_Message`.

Comment: Would you like to add an example of a wrong string to your question, and accept your own answer with a correct string?

Comment: Worked for me. The funny thing is that [the MS documentation example uses dots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/put-ui-strings-into-resources)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#refer-to-a-string-resource-identifier-from-code) the documentation says "." characters should be replaced with "/" when resources are queried from code.

> If a resource name is segmented (it contains "." characters), then replace dots with forward slash ("/") characters in the resource name. Property identifiers, for example, contain dots; so you'd need to do this substition in order to load one of those from code.